# Azure Service principal name

Tags: azure

May I know how in Azure CLI , to get back the name of the service principal name by the client ID >

And CLI command I can do that ?

I would like to see if I can get back the service principal name

Answer (score 0):

***I have reproduced from my end, Using the below Cli command you can get the output:***

***xxx-Clientid***

```
az ad sp show --id xxx
```

[image]

***Alternatively, Using below powershell command you can get :***

```
Get-AzureADServicePrincipal
```

[image]

***References taken from:***

- [az ad sp | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-sp-show)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azadserviceprincipal?view=azps-8.2.0